# 3D Trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry, 3d

So this is the question. There is a cuboid $ABCDEFGH$; $ABCD$ is the horizontal rectangular base and $EFGH$ is the horizontal rectangular top. $AB = 4x$, $AE = 3x$, and $BC = y$. If the angle between the skew lines $BH$ and $AD$ is $\theta$ show that $y \sin \theta - 5x \cos \theta = 0$.

I have attempted this question as follows: Since $BD$ is coplanar to $AD$, the angle $\theta$ is also the angle between $AD$ and $BD$. Then, looking at the right-angled triangle formed by $AB$, $AD$ and $BD$, we get $\sin \theta = 4x/BD$, and $\cos \theta = y/BD$. Making both equal to $BD$ and then rearranging algebraically I get $y \sin \theta - 4x \cos \theta = 0$. Not sure why the question says $5x$ and I am getting $4x$ with everything else correct. Any help please?

Comment: If you draw a diagram of your cuboid, I think you'll find $AD$ doesn't have the same angle with $BD$ as it does with $BH$. I recommend working in a $3$-dimensional Cartesian coordinate system to find the sine and cosine of the angle between $\vec{BH}$ and $\vec{AD}$.

Comment: the angle between $BH$ and $AD$ equals the angle between $BH$ and $BC$ since $BC$ is parallel to $AD$.

Comment: Thank you both very much! Managed to find my mistake and get the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since $AD$ and $BC$ are parallel, the angle between $HB$ and $AD$ is the same as the angle between $HB$ and $BC$. Within the cuboid lies the right-angled triangle $HBC$. Using basic trigonometric ratios, we can see that $\sin \theta = HC/BH$, and therefore $\sin \theta = 5x/BH$. We get the $5x$ using Pythagoras to determine $HC$. Rearranging we get $BH = 5x/\sin \theta$. Now we take cosine and find that $\cos \theta = y/BH$. Rearranging we get $BH = y/\cos \theta$. Therefore we can say that $5x/\sin \theta = y/\cos \theta$. Rearranging the algebra gives us our solution.